# Solr Config API: json overlay affecting managed-schema?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 6.1.0, in a local environment. When using the config API to change the behaviour of `solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler`, this somehow affects other fields in the index (and adds extra fields to managed-schema.xml).

This affects a few fields, always in the same way: `content_type` disappears from the query result (still in the schema though!) and instead there is `Content-Type` (which is added to managed-schema). My `<solr_url>/config/overlay` looks like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "overlay":{
    "znodeVersion":0,
    "requestHandler":{"/update/extract":{
        "name":"/update/extract",
        "class":"solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler",
        "defaults":{
          "fmap.content":"content",
          "wt":"json",
          "indent":true},
        "useParams":"fmap.content"}}}}
```

The indexing works fine (and is using `content_type`, as expected) when this overlay is not there. I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere, but I have no idea where (and why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **useParams=fmap.content**. That's a reference to a set of additional configuration parameters. For some reason it is using a name as one of the possible parameters, which might be confusing things.

So, this may mean you have a params.json file that has a section **fmap.content** and some things defined there. Including ones that change defaults set otherwise.

Specifically, by default you somehow have a parameter called [lowernames](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-InputParameters) set to true and your override disables it.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. The class has three default values total, one being `lowernames`. I somehow though `useParams:fmap.content` would only changed this parameter and keep the others. Passed all of them to the overlay, it works now.